# How to fix max drawn entries on Line Chart?

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm putting a lot of entries to chart. Like 100-200 of them. It's running stats at each second. So my graph looks very messy when we getting bigger and bigger reached range. So is it possible to fix X axis values that will be drawn on graph? For example if we have 200+ values of 10 km just draw 30 of them also at 10 km on even checkpoints to make graph less accurate but more understandable

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MpChart draws every point which is given by programmer, it never decides which should be drawn or not, so I think the only way is to find the 30 checkpoints by some filter function and set it to MpChart, then call chart.invalidate

Comment: Looks like it's the only option. Thanks